# How to plot my data without zeros in input

Tags: matlab, plot

I have some big data arrays witch contain some 0 0 rows
I want to print my plot without them, how?
The arrays look like
(its part or (100000:2:2:N) array so cant just del those rows)
A(:,:,1,5):

```
    12 60
    12.1 80
    12.2 75
    0 0
    0 0
    0 0
```

Thx

ps right now i plot with plot(A(:,1,1,5),A(:,2,1,5)) ; how can i plots them as scatter(points) with different length of pairs

thx a lot

Comment: Do you only want to ignore double pairs of zeros at the end? What about assigning it to a different intermediate variable and then deleting the irrelevant rows?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
zero_ind = any(A(:,:,1,5), 2);   %// You might need to call squeeze here depending on the dimensions
plot(A(zero_ind,1,1,5),A(zero_ind,2,1,5));
```

Answer (score 1):

`plot()` will ignore any input which is `NaN`, so assuming '0' is not a valid value in your data, replace all zeros with `NaN`. 
 For example, the following code will only display 7 out of 10 points:

```
>> x = 10*rand(1,10);
>> y = 10*rand(1,10);
>> x([1,5,6])= 0;
>> x(x == 0) = NaN;
>> y(y == 0) = NaN;
>> plot(x,y,'.');
```

Comment: small typo. you should use `y(x == 0)=NaN` otherwise you could/will get problems when not those 3 elements in x also are 0 in y.

Comment: @The Minion - why? I've tried it with either x, y or both `NaN`, and the plot was correct. Do you have an example?

Comment: When you do this you set all y-values which are zero to NaN, same goes for all x values. Now take data like: `x=[0 1 2 3 0 0 0]` and `y= [9 0 15 0 9 1 8]` THe only point plotted after changing those zeros to NaN is [2,15]. Yet you would want to plot [1,0][2,15][3,0]. If you do `y(x==0)=NaN;x(x==0)=NaN;` you won't have that loss of data. Also take care with the order (if you change x first you won't change anyhting at y)

Comment: @TheMinion - I think normally you would be right, but I think the SO wants to discard any '0 0' rows. That is why I wrote "assuming '0' is not a valid value in your data". Anyway, good input.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you only want to remove rows where *both* columns are equal to `0`. What you can do is the following:

```
A(sum(A==0,2)==2,:)=NaN;
```

Explained: it creates a logical array with ones where any element of `A` is equal to `0`. It then sums along the columns. When both columns are equal to `0`, the sum will be 2. It then replaces everything with `NaN` that will be ignored by the `plot` function.

Then plot:

```
plot(A(:,1), A(:,2))
```